# Web API and angularjs to download Excel file

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have successfully uploaded an Excel spreadsheet to my file server via the Web API.  Now I need the ability to download that same file and allow the user to modify it.  With my current code the result is just garbage.

This is my server code -

```
factory.downloadFile = function(id) {
    return $http.get(serviceBase1 + 'downloadFile/' + id).then(function (datafile) {
        return datafile.data;
    });
}
```

This is my controller code in the API which is borrowed from another post -

```
[Route("downloadFile/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage DowloadFile(string id)
{
    var fileInfo = FileInformationRepository.GetFileInfoById(id);

    var localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments/" + fileInfo.FileName);

    if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    else
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileInfo.FileName;
        return result;
    }
}
```

LocalFilePath is correct - C:\Development\OpticalSystems\OpticalSystems.WebApi\UploadedDocuments\Quotation Sheet (s).xls
The header on the data returned is - application/json, text/plain, */*. And the data returned is - �ࡱ�, which of course is something that I can not open.  I know that I am close to making this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by making these changes to my controller -

```
[Route("downloadFile/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage DowloadFile(string id)
{
    var fileName = FileInformationRepository.GetFileInfoById(id).FileName;
    string filePath = string.Concat(GetDownloadPath(), "\\", fileName);

    HttpResponseMessage result;
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
    }
    else
    {// serve the file to the client
        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
    }

    return result;
}

public static string GetDownloadPath()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments");
}
```